Calcular años meses y días entre dos fechas
Estoy haciendo una app que pida tu fecha de nacimiento y calcule cuantos años, meses y días tienes en base a la fecha actual, he empezado a hacer mi algoritmo pero veo mi app no tiene precisión al devolver la fecha, me podrían ayudar?


const inputDia = document.getElementById("dia");
const inputMes = document.getElementById("mes");
const inputYear = document.getElementById("year");
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");

let fechaInicio = new Date("1980-03-13").getTime();
let fechaFin = new Date().getTime();

let diff = fechaFin - fechaInicio;

let dias = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

let diasResult = Math.floor(dias % 365);
let yearsResult = Math.floor(dias / 365);

let vector = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

let contador = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < vector.length - 1; i++) {
  if (diasResult >= vector[i]) {
    diasResult = diasResult - vector[i];
    contador++;
  } else {
    if (diasResult === 0) {
      break;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(diasResult);
console.log(contador);



Lo estoy intentando obteniendo los días que hay entre las dos fechas y redondeando con Math.floor,hasta ahí todo va correcto ya que los días que me sale de diferencia si están correctos, tuve una idea de dividir los días entre 365 para ver cuántos años hay entre las dos fechas, después para ver si sobraban días calcule el resto de los días con 365, y con ese resto empiezo a trabajar para averiguar los días y meses ya que los años ya los tengo,
uso un vector para representar los días que tienen los meses del año y hago un bucle para ir viendo hasta donde llega, el contador me sirve para recoger saber en que mes se detuvo y diasResult para saber cuantos días sobraron después de todo, pero no me sale una fecha precisa, suele variar cuanto mas días haya de diferencia entre ambas fechas mas falla la precisión del algoritmo, tienen idea de como mejorar el código o de repente una manera mas fácil de hacerlo?

Si no quieres reinventar la rueda, utiliza una librería para trabajar con fechas como moment.js que te deja hacer operaciones como la diferencia entre fechas con facilidad: https://momentjs.com/

@ordago MomentJS es una librería no recomendada ya por sus propios autores. Tal vez mirar otras opciones sería lo ideal al recomendar una librería. Más información en la pagina del estado de proyecto de MomentJS

No se que tan recomendable sea o no pero he investigado un poco y he usado la librería para mi algoritmo y lo que antes me había llevado líneas y líneas de código y  aun así el algoritmo siendo muy impreciso con moment.js he resuelto el problema literalmente con 4 líneas de código, ahora estoy en duda si debo o no usar esta librería y que otras librerías hay que sean "mejores"?

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, estoy haciendo un algoritmo que pida una fecha y me devuelva la diferencia que hay entre fechas en formato años, meses y dias, por ejemplo, ingreso una fecha (10-12-2021) y la respuesta por poner un ejemplo es 3 años, 5 meses, 14 días, me explico? Y la pregunta que tu has enviado no es igual, de igual forma ya encontré la solución al algoritmo, gracias

@PedroFerreira en la pagina que enlazo en mi comentario anterior, se exponen algunas sugerencias alternativas al uso de MomentJS, por ejemplo: Day.js o date-fns. Toma en cuenta siempre la compatibilidad requerida. Aunque, personalmente, prefiero realizar los cálculos por mi cuenta y no usar librerías externas, pero eso ya es una decisión muy personal. Las librerías te ayudan a acelerar el desarrollo, pero cuando se rompen o se descontinúan, tienes que buscarte la vida.

@MauricioContreras gracias por la información y por citar las fuentes, se ve que me he quedado desfasado.



  // creamos una función que recibe os parámetros adecuados
function edad( primerFecha, segundaFecha ) {

      // instanciamos los objetos "Date" respetando el formato "yyyy-MM-dd"
   var primera = new Date( primerFecha ).getTime();
   var segunda = new Date( segundaFecha ).getTime();   

      // creamos un objeto "Date" con la diferencia entre fechas
   let diff = new Date( segunda - primera );
   
      // le restamos "1970" años a la fecha, ya que los objetos "Date"
      // contienen el numero de segundos desde esa fecha hasta la requerida
   diff.setFullYear( diff.getFullYear() - 1970 );
   
      //  creamos la cadena que devolverá la función
   let edad = diff.getFullYear() + " años, " + diff.getMonth() + " meses y " + diff.getDate() + " días ";   
   return edad;
}

let numA = 10;
let numB = 10;

for( let i = 0; i < 12; i++ ) {
   let fechaA = "20" + numA + "-03-19";
   let fechaB = "20" + numB + "-02-12";
   console.log( edad( fechaA, fechaB )); 
   numA++;
}   

console.log();
console.log( "---" );
console.log();

mes = [ "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12" ];

for( let i = 0; i < 11; i++ ) {
   let fechaA = "2020-" + mes[ i ] + "-12";
   let fechaB = "2020-" + mes[ i + 1 ] + "-12";
   console.log( edad( fechaB, fechaA )); 
} 




Responder sólo con código, por más comentarios que pongas al mismo, se considera de baja calidad. Por otro lado es muy probable que esta pregunta ya se haya realizado en el sitio, por lo cual sería duplicada.

@MauricioContreras, tu comentario es un poco contradictorio, un código comentado, por definición, no es solo código, pero si vamos más alla, pones un enlace a una respuesta que tiene el mismo formato que criticas... y encima es errónea...
